# How to change a label value automatically when we change other text fields in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, material-ui, widget

I have used TextEditingController to fetch the changes in the text fields.
Using the same I created a submit button and when the user clicks the submit button, it will calculate the values and update the label at the end.

Below is the code.

```
//main.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:english_words/english_words.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome!!',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('scaffold appbar')),
        body: Center(
          child: CoinDetails(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CoinDetails extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CoinDetailsState createState() => _CoinDetailsState();
}

class _CoinDetailsState extends State<CoinDetails> {
  TextEditingController coinController = TextEditingController();//replacement for onChanged event handling of a button
  TextEditingController priceController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController amountController = TextEditingController();
  double _price=0;
  double _amount=0;
  double _commission=0;
  double _totalCost=0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TextStyle textStyle = Theme.of(context).textTheme.title;
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
      child:Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextField(
            controller: coinController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: 'Coin',
            hintText: "e.g. BTT",
            labelStyle: textStyle,
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)
            ),
          ),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
            /*onChanged: (String string){
            setState(() {
              name = string;
            });
            },*/
          ),
          TextField(
            controller: priceController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Price',
              hintText: "e.g. BTT",
              labelStyle: textStyle,
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)
              ),
            ),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
            /*onChanged: (String string){
            setState(() {
              name = string;
            });
            },*/
          ),
          TextField(
            controller: amountController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Amount',
              hintText: "e.g. BTT purchase amount invested",
              labelStyle: textStyle,
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)
              ),
            ),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
            /*onChanged: (String string){
            setState(() {
              name = string;
            });
            },*/
          ),
          RaisedButton(
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
              textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight,
              child: Text('Submit',textScaleFactor: 1.5),
              onPressed: (){
                setState(() {
                  _calculate();
                });
              }),

          Text("Commission: "+_commission.toString()+" Total Cost: "+_totalCost.toString()),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
  String _calculate(){
    _price = double.parse(priceController.text);
    _amount = double.parse(amountController.text);
    _commission = _amount * 0.002;
    _totalCost = _amount + _commission;
  }
}
```

I want to remove this submit button and update the value automatically when the user changes the Price or Amount text fields or both.

[image: App screen UI]

Please guide me how to set that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `onChanged` callback of the `TextField` widget. It fires every time the value of the `TextField` changes.

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String name = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Your name is: $name'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextFormField(
              onChanged: (String value) {
               /// The value is the value of the TextField.
               /// You can perform the calculations here:
               setState(() => name = value);
              },
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Name', hintText: 'Please enter your name'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Also, the precision is showing wrong for 700 and showing correct for 70 and 7000.
Can you please check it once.

[image: code snap]

Comment: sorry by mistake I added to your answer and instead of question and it is not allowing me to update again. Can you check the details I added now. 

Also, the precision is showing wrong for 700 and showing correct for 70 and 7000.
Can you please check it once.